# Serilog not writing every method to database

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I'm writing MVC application, using the serilog to write logs to mssql.
When I call some methods, they do not appear in the log but only the first one does.
Any Ideas?

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{

        Configuration = configuration;
        var listener = new global::SerilogTraceListener.SerilogTraceListener();
        Trace.AutoFlush = true;
        Trace.Listeners.Add(listener);
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .AuditTo
          .MSSqlServer(
                connectionString: configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                tableName: "Logs", autoCreateSqlTable: true, schemaName: "Diagnostics",
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose)
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
          .Enrich.WithThreadName()
          .Enrich.WithThreadId()
          .Enrich.FromLogContext()
          .WriteTo.Trace()
          .CreateLogger();
}//end ctor
```

In HomeController:

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> logger;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
    this.logger = logger;
}
public IActionResult Index()
{
        TryExecute();

        return View();
}

public void TryExecute()
{
    //logger.LogInformation("try me here not async");
}
```

Result in the database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yNpY.jpg

As you can see, The Execution of the Index method is logged, but the TryExecute is not...
What can I do?

Comment: Isn't that just ASP.NET Core logging which actions it's calling? Without Serilog at all, you'd see the same thing on the console... but there's nothing to log *every method call* going on there, as far as I can see.

Comment: For start, I want it to log at least that the method invoked

Comment: And every method that TryExecute invokes? And every method that *those* methods invoke? I suspect you'd find that became impractical pretty quickly. But if you really want that, you should probably look into an AOP solution. I wouldn't expect a framework that focuses on just the *logging* side to do anything for you there.

Comment: I've thought about it... but if there is an option to do so automatically, it's better for me for now.. thanks anyway :)